# DB2 Connection is not working in DBeaver when i'm trying to connect

Tags: db2, dbeaver

i'm trying to connect DB2 Database in DBeaver client, i tried with some of DB2 Drivers, but always it's showing the same error:

Error

[image: 1]

My drivers:

Drivers

[image: 2]

What could be the problem?

Comment: Seems, that you use Db2 Connect as a gateway to access your Db2 for Z/OS or Db2 for IBM i (aka Db2 for iSeries) database. You should use the corresponding connection type instead of Db2 LUW. DBEaver probably issues different sql statements internally depending on the connection type chosen as in this case, when it tries to select from SYSCAT.SCHEMATA view, which exists in Db2 for LUW databases, but doesn't exist in other Db2 systems mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Maven is installed on your PC and available globally on your environment variables